# T-SQL Procedure split and join on sub columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Not really sure how to explain this so I just start with the example.

Say I have a table like this which can include several rows:

```
id  Type    Text
1   Test    Failure A=123 B=444 C=43343 Error=4 ErroDes=1
```

I also have a static Error and ErrorDes table which look like this

```
Id  Code    Description
1   1       Error1
2   4       Error4
```

How can I split up the information from the column into seperate fields and also join in the info from the subtables.

Expected result would be something like this:

```
Type    Field1    FieldA    FieldB  FieldC  Error   ErrorDes
Test    Failure   123       444     43343   Error4  Error1
```

I used the same table for joining in the example but this is 2 tables in the db.

So to help with this I have a split function in the database.

And if I first split the Text field on "space" and then on "=" I get everything I need (or atleast all the columns in seperate rows)

```
cross apply dbo.Split(a.Text, ' ') s
cross apply dbo.Split(s.Value, '=') s2
```

I get "TokenID" and "Value" field back from the split function.
The output from that looks like this:

```
TokenID   Value         TokenID   Value
  1       Failure          1      Failure     
  2       A=123            1      A
  2       A=123            2      123
  3       B=444            1      B
  3       B=444            2      444
  4       C=43343          1      C
  4       C=43343          2      43343          
  5       Error=4          1      Error
  5       Error=4          2      4
  6       ErrorDes=1       1      ErrorDes
  6       ErrorDes=1       2      1
```

I hope you understand what I ment and can help me how this can be solved.

Comment: I removed the "mysql" tag because the syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Comment: You can then use `pivot` to put the data back into a single row.

Comment: Could you give me an example? Only heard of pivot in use with Excel and this is for a stored procedure which has nothing to do with Excel.

Comment: Please, google "Sql Server Pivot". Surprisingly you'll get samples of "Sql Server Pivot"! And not only samples!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use something like the folowing UDF function to cross apply

```
create function udf_ReturnTextSplit(@vText varchar(100))
returns @rt table (
    Field1 varchar(100),
    FieldA varchar(100),
    FieldB varchar(100)
) as begin
    declare @st varchar(100) = @vText + ' '
    declare @sti varchar(100)
    declare @stj varchar(100)
    insert into @rt (Field1, FieldA, FieldB) values (null, null, null)
    declare @i int = charindex(' ', @st)

    while @i > 0 begin        
        set @sti = SUBSTRING(@st, 1, @i)        
        set @st = substring(@st, @i + 1, 100)        

        set @i = CHARINDEX('=', @sti)
        if @i > 0 begin
            set @stj = substring(@sti, @i + 1, 100)
            set @sti = substring(@sti, 1, @i - 1)
            if @sti = 'A' update @rt set FieldA = @stj                
            if @sti = 'B' update @rt set FieldB = @stj                
        end else begin
            update @rt set Field1 = @sti
        end

        set @i = charindex(' ', @st)
    end    

    return
end
go

select * from dbo.udf_ReturnTextSplit('Failure A=123 B=444 C=43343 Error=4 ErroDes=1')
```

Comment: Thanks for your answear. This is almost working perfect. Only problem is that I have to add a blank space at the end to get it to work. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: the best idea is really `declare @st varchar(100) = @vText + ' '`